# Custom object collection

Tags: excel, vba, collections

I'm trying to create a collection of custom objects in Excel using VBA.

I've tried this but I can't see why it's wrong:

```
Dim data As String

Dim myCol  As Collection
Set myCol = New Collection

Dim myObj As myClass
Set myObj = PutData(data)

'Error (438) here: Object does not admit this property or method
myCol.Add(myObj)



 Public Function PutData(data As String) As myClass

     Dim p As New myClass
     p.data = data 
     Set PutData= p

 End Function
```

How could I create a custom object collection?

I come from C# where this is done as simple as initializing the List or collection and adding the item, like this:

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
list.Add(myCustomobject>();
```

Comment: correct syntax for adding should be similar to this syntax: `myCol.Add item:=yourObject, key:=CStr(Num)`. Have you tried that? See [THIS LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264685%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: If you are using brackets, you should use `Call` as well: `Call myCol.Add(myObj)`. Alternativeky you can use just `myCol.Add myObj` without brackets

Comment: Thanks, both solutions (KazJaw and simoco) worked. I prefer myCol.Add myObj for simplicity.